# ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be inherited from `kivymd.app.MDApp`

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

For some reason I can't get the MDTextField to work. I feel like its something simple but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

```
import kivymd
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField


class MainApp(MDApp):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
    theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

MainApp().run()
```

'
KV
'

```
#:import MDTextField kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextField

FloatLayout:
    size_hint: .8, .8
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    spacing: dp(100)
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDTextField:
```

Answer (score 3):

So apparently my issue wasn't with the textfield, it was theme manager. so instead of

```
import kivymd
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField


class MainApp(MDApp):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
    theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

MainApp().run()
```

I was supposed to use

```
import kivymd
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "BMI"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: You don't need the `import kivymd` and `from kivy.app import App` also...

Comment: You are the best. Thank you, had the same error too